# Ie11 not reading print.css file

Tags: css, print-css

I admit, I am annoyed at ie at this point! It seems no matter what the css is within my print.css file nothing wants to be applied to ie.

My stylesheet works fine in chrome, safari and firefox, just not ie.

The base structure looking like this

```
@media print {
    .noPrint,
    .displayOnly{
        display: none;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .somediv {
            width: 100% !important;
            max-width: 100% !important;
            min-width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
}
```

and my link to the css looks like this

```
<link href="css/print.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="print">
```

Is there something special ie needs that I am missing? I tried adding 'alternative' to see if that would work, but it was for not.

Comment: When you look at the loaded files in IE's dev tools, is it not loading your `.css` or is it not applying your `.css`?

Comment: @RyanWilson, I appears not able to find the file when I search for it. However, I'm not sure if that's because it only finds the file when printing or not.

Comment: it seems that IE has classically had problems with nested media queries -- do the main print rules work if you remove the nested portion?

Comment: @derelict, no none of the styles are working. :(

Comment: @zazvorniki Sounds to me like a security setting in IE is preventing your `.css` from loading, try adding the url of the site to trusted sites under IE settings.

Comment: @RyanWilson, I've tested this on multiple computers though and it isn't working anywhere. I can't expect the user to add the stylesheet to their trusted sites. Plus this is an internal application on our own servers I can't see our company blocking their own site haha

Comment: @zazvorniki Are you running this locally for testing, or is it published to a test server?

Comment: @RyanWilson, locally and to three test servers

Comment: @zazvorniki Are your script files loading? Or are all files failing to load via IE?

Comment: @RyanWilson, Everything else is working fine the only thing not working in this print css and only in ie. The print css file works in every other browser.

Comment: Maybe you can add the code in the `<head>` tag as well

Comment: @SuperDJ, the entire print css instead of a separate file? That's unfortunately not an option here it's against our "code quality" policy.

Comment: @zazvorniki Is the complete CSS file in the head? Just the html ofcourse

Comment: @SuperDJ, not sure what you mean? The links for both the reg and this style sheet are in the head

Comment: Maybe this can help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/256bec8f-71c1-429e-87cd-b61bdf0c8349/ie-11-edge-css-print-bug?forum=iewebdevelopment

Comment: @SuperDJ, I have actually read that quite deeply. This is not in edge just ie11, plus I am not using word press and this is not a 'fixed' layout.

Comment: Have you tried unnesting your media queries and placing them together with an `AND`?

Comment: @RyanWilson, I have not tried using AND, but I do have unnested properties that you can see in my example that are not working. the displayOnly and noPrint elements are still being printed...

Comment: Have you tried dropping the "media" tag from your link? Check this article out: http://lawrencenaman.com/optimisation/print-media-queries-not-working/